# How to use regex in a SPARQL query with an umlaut?

Tags: sparql

I tried to execute a SPARQL query that uses regex to get all resources whose label contains a certain string (case insensitive, that's why I use regex). Unfortunately, no resource that contains an umlaut is being returned. The regex should match any label that contains Sigmund or sigmund.

Example:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?s WHERE {{
        ?s rdfs:label ?label .
        FILTER ( LANG(?label) = "en" )
        BIND (STR(?label) AS ?label_text) 
        FILTER(REGEX(?label_text, "Sigmund", "i"))
}}
```

This answer for this query is the following:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Analysands_of_Sigmund_Freud
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Books_about_Sigmund_Freud
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Books_by_Sigmund_Freud
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Case_studies_by_Sigmund_Freud
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Compositions_by_Sigmund_Romberg
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Cultural_depictions_of_Sigmund_Freud
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Essays_by_Sigmund_Freud
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Musicals_by_Sigmund_Romberg
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Operas_by_Sigmund_Theophil_Staden
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Sigmund_Freud
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sigmund_Freud
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Sigmund_Freud's_views
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Songs_with_music_by_Sigmund_Romberg
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Translators_of_Sigmund_Freud
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Works_about_Sigmund_Freud
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Works_by_Sigmund_Freud
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sigmund_Mauderli
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sigmund_Spaeth
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barbara_Boggs_Sigmund
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ben_Sigmund
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sigmund
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Anne_Sigmund
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dagobert_Sigmund_von_Wurmser
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bernhard_Sigmund_Schultze
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sigmund_Eisner
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cabinet_of_Sigmundur_Davíð_Gunnlaugsson
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Carl_Ludwig_Sigmund
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Anne_Marie_Sigmund
```

The problem is, that this list is incomplete. There is at least one resource missing ([Sigmund Jähn](https://dbpedia.org/page/Sigmund_J%C3%A4hn))

I think that this happens because of the umlaut, since Sigmund Jähn is the only resource that contains such a character.

I already tried to use the whole name for the regex, using the u flag as regex option, writing the ä in unicode, using \X instead of the ä or replacing the ä with an a, but nothing works.

Comment: your query is worst case as it will scan the whole dataset, and on DBpedia you'll usually get anything found in a configured limit. I suggest to use the Virtuoso fulltext index here: `PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?s WHERE {
        ?s rdfs:label ?label .
        FILTER ( LANG(?label) = "en" )
        ?label bif:contains '"Sigmund"'
}`

Comment: Thank you! It works as intended now. (And much faster!)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue specifically with [`http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sigmund_J%C3%A4hn`](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sigmund_J%C3%A4hn), presumably not related to umlauts.

While its page and e.g. the Turtle representation list an English `rdfs:label`, the [DBpedia’s endpoint](https://dbpedia.org/sparql) doesn’t find it:

```
SELECT * WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sigmund_J%C3%A4hn> rdfs:label ?o . }
```

It finds the labels in *all* other languages (19 of 20), and most of them contain the umlaut. I have no idea why it’s not finding the English one.

> case insensitive, that's why I use regex

You could avoid using `REGEX()` here, because SPARQL offers [`LCASE()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-lcase)/[`UCASE()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-ucase), which can be used in [`CONTAINS()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-contains):

```
?s rdfs:label ?label .
FILTER( LANG(?label) = "en" ) .
FILTER( CONTAINS(LCASE(?label), "sigmund") ) .
```

This filter checks if the lower-cased `?label` contains the string "sigmund".

Suggested by UninformedUser:
A better alternative, but specific to Virtuoso’s triple store (which is used by the DBpedia endpoint), is using [`bif:contains`](https://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlrulefulltext/) :

```
?s rdfs:label ?label .
FILTER( LANG(?label) = "en" ) .
?label bif:contains "'Sigmund'" . # the string value itself is enclosed in quotes to allow to search for spaces or other non-alphanumeric chars
```

It uses a full text index

Comment: the query would have to be `select distinct ?c where {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sigmund_Jähn> a ?c } LIMIT 100`

Comment: the result with regex or contains is most likely incomplete because Virtusos resp. DBpedia will return whatever it finds in a given time, it has a so-called anytime feature - the more efficient way is to use a fullext index via bif:contains: `SELECT DISTINCT ?s WHERE {         ?s rdfs:label ?label .         FILTER ( LANG(?label) = "en" )         ?label bif:contains '"Sigmund"' }`

Comment: @UninformedUser: Nice, I wasn’t aware of `bif:contains` – thank you!  Regarding the umlaut encoding:  Do you know why it finds 19/20 labels when using `dbr:Sigmund_J%C3%A4hn`, but 20/20 when using `dbr:Sigmund_Jähn`? There also seem to be differences for other properties. I would have expected to find identical RDF, or nothing in one case. How comes it’s a mix?